# Errors building IPP 2021 app with 9.0-legacy on Mac Mini 2020 M1

Tags: macos, gcc, apple-m1, intel-ipp

I am working on a **Mac Mini 2020 M1** with **Big Sur 11.4** as **development-engine**
and need to rebuild our libs using **gcc 10.2** targetting **MacOS 10.15 (Catalina)**.
Since our source uses Intel **IPP** and IPP v2021.2.0 states, it can be used for **MacOS 10.15**,
I suppose it can be compiled on Catalina, allthough the question is:

***How to manage this on Big Sur 11.4 (my dev-engine)?***

I have to use **IPP v9.0 legacy** as well, and are currently facing plenty of errors.
(e.g.

`ippi90legacy_redef.h:430:36: error: conflicting types for 'legacy90ippiFulterBilateral_8u_C1R`)

Has anybody out there gone through this, and maybe share some insights, how to manage this pain in the neck??

Thnxalot

Answer (score 0):

For a quick "solution", I have commented out the *"Bilateral"* definition duplicates in *ippi90legacy_redef.h*, as I don't need them, and now it compiles without moaning.